# How do I get customize values from SQL query

Tags: sql

Below table 'mydata' has four columns payId,custId,rScore,bScore

```
payId   custId  rScore  bScore

A        1         0.2       0
A        2         0.3       1
A        4         0.65      1
A        1         0.35      0
B        3         0.5       1
B        5         0.3       1
B        5         0.85      0
```

range the rScore as:
    a) rScore<0.5 then '<0.5',
    b) rScore >= 0.5 then '>=0.5'

### Find

1. count of distinct custId based on each payId and range.
2. calculate ratio (total number of 1s)/(total number of 1s & 0s) based on each payId and range

### I want the output as mentioned below from SQL query

```
payId   range  custId  ratio
A        <0.5   2        0.33  
A        >=0.5  1        1
B        <0.5   1        1
B        >=0.5  2        0.5
```

This is what I have tried but I am not getting the desired output -

```
SELECT payId, IF(rscore< 0.5, '<0.5','>=0.5') As range, 
Case 
    When rscore< 0.5 then Count(Distict(custId))
    When rscore >=0.5 then Count(Distict(custId)))
End AS custID
From mydata
```

Comment: did you try using CASE statement?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Does the expected result really match the sample data?

Comment: have you tried anything yourself? you shouldn't be asking others to write the code for you.

Comment: @Ted I am new here and I didnt expect someone to code for me, but I was stuck here. A friend asked me to post, then he said I didn't know that the community went so rude. Anyhow I have posted what I did

Comment: @Akansha I don't see how any of the previous comments can be considered as "rude"?  It's normal to ask for clarifications when not all is clear. Also, text doesn't show emotions, so when a comment looks "angry" it's often just how the reader percieves it.  Asking for "what have you tried" is mostly to avoid students who want their homework done for them, or highly payed consultants trying to outsource their job to a free source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to GROUP BY on that calculated range.
One way is to repeat that CASE WHEN calculation in the GROUP BY.

```
SELECT 
 payId, 
 (CASE WHEN rscore < 0.5 THEN '<0.5' WHEN rscore >= 0.5 THEN '>=0.5' END) AS range, 
 COUNT(DISTINCT custId) AS TotalCustId,
 AVG(ratio) AS AverageRatio
FROM mydata
GROUP BY 
 payId, 
 (CASE WHEN rscore < 0.5 THEN '<0.5' WHEN rscore >= 0.5 THEN '>=0.5' END)
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

Or use a subquery and group on that

```
SELECT payId, range, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT custId) AS TotalCustId, 
  AVG(ratio) AS AverageRatio
FROM (
    SELECT payId, custId, ratio,
    (CASE
     WHEN rscore < 0.5 THEN '<0.5'
     WHEN rscore >= 0.5 THEN '>=0.5'
     END) AS range
    FROM mydata
) AS Q
GROUP BY payId, range
ORDER BY payId, range;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to group your data on the first to columns, since you don't want all rows in your output. This should work if you are using MSSQL.

```
; WITH cte_range AS (
    SELECT
        *
        ,CASE WHEN rScore < 0.5 THEN '<0.5' ELSE '>=0.5' END AS range
    FROM
        mydata
)
SELECT
    payId
    ,range
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT custId) as distinctCustomers
    ,AVG(bScore) AS ratio
FROM 
    cte_range
GROUP BY
    payId
    ,range
ORDER BY
    payId
    ,range;
```

Answer (score 0):

MSSQL Solution

```
with cte as (
  select *,range=iif(rscore< 0.5, '<0.5','>=0.5') from t
) 
  select payid,range,cnt_custid=count(distinct (custid)),
    ratio=avg(bScore) from cte
  group by payid,range
  ORDER BY payId, range;
```